# login dialog using shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I would like to make a userlogin details, using shared preferences.

when I load the application and click on the login button,
a login dialog will pop up.
After I've typed in , it will toast a greeting to the user, such as welcome [username].
When the user login again, it will toast a message welcome back [username]. The user do not have to type his/her name again to go in the application.
In fact, when the user click login, it will toast welcome back [username], and he/she can continue with the application.

However, 
in my code, whenever I select login, I'll have to type the username.
Even when I login again, I still have to type the username.

Can someone guide me along with my code?

logcat:

```
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fuellogproject/com.example.fuellogproject.homeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:160)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:366)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.example.fuellogproject.homeActivity.<init>(homeActivity.java:19)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2025)
01-27 18:04:00.266: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     ... 11 more
```

This is my code

```
public void CheckUser(View v) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(homeActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.login);
    dialog.setTitle("Login");
    final EditText editTextUserName = (EditText) dialog
        .findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
    Button btnLogIn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.loginBTN);
    // get The User name and Password
    String userName = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
    if (access_token != null) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("username", userName);
        editor.commit();
        String getUser = prefs.getString("username", userName);
        Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, "Welcome," + getUser,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        dialog.dismiss();
        Intent mainact = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainact);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(homeActivity.this, "Welcome back," + userName,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent mainact = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainact);
    }
    // get the Refferences of views
    // Set On ClickListener
    btnLogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("access_token", "<save value>");
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: What is the line `homeActivity.java:19` that throws the NPE ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String access_token = preferences.getString("username", null);

    if(access_token!=null){
    showMain();  //inside show main you write your logic for toast, redirect to the desired view
    }
```

Now if **username** is present in **shared preference** , then it will go to your desired activity else you can still show the **LoginActivity**, and put the below code in click listener of your Login Button

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();    
 editor.putString("access_token","<save value>");
 editor.commit();
```

Comment: I've edited it, you mean like that?
It was said that for SharedPrefrences must be final

Comment: @chloe, declare `SharedPreference as private variable outside the onCreateView(..)` and initialize it inside the method, then i wont be asking for `final`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have different key when reading and writing to/from shared preferences:

```
editor.putString("user_name", userName);
```

and

```
String getUser = prefs.getString("username", userName);
```

in particularly, keys `User_name` and `userename`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    1. Use the same string to save and retrieve values...
     "editor.putString("user_name", userName); 
                                    editor.commit(); 
                                    String getUser = prefs.getString("username".."
    "user_name" while putString and "username" while getString 

     2. Where are you retrieving the sharedPref value? it has to be without checking the edittext value if you want the user to log in without typing his/her name.
i.e. String getUser = prefs.getString("username", userName);   -with a null check when user clicks login
```